# Login Form changes css when focus on password input type

Tags: html, css

This form works fine in Chrome and Firefox. But on IE, this going crazy.

You can see the form here:http://www.alsite.com.br/clinicadosono

Why this is not working fine in IE8? IE9 sounds good!

This is the code of my login form:

```
<form class="form-1" action="" method="post">
    <p><input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Login" required /></p>
    <p><input type="password" name='senha' placeholder="Senha" required /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Entrar" /></p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <p class="clique_aqui_cadastro">Não possui cadastro? <a href="#">Clique aqui</a></p>
</form>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
.form-1 {
    width: 256px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.form-1 input[type=text],
.form-1 input[type=password] {
    width: 222px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 8px 4px 8px 25px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;

    /* Styles */
    border: 1px solid #d2d3d4; /* Fallback */
    background: #f1f1f1 url(../imagens/icone_login.png) left no-repeat;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

    /* Font styles */
    color: #878787;
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
    font-size:12px;

    outline:none;

    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.form-1 input[type=password] {
    background: #f1f1f1 url(../imagens/icone_pass.png) left no-repeat;
    width: 126px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.form-1 input[type=submit] {
    width: 90px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #78a7a7;
    border: 1px solid #6db5b5;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    float:left;
    /* Font styles */
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.form-1 input[type=submit]:hover{
    color:#000;
}
```

PS: I've tried to separate css of `[type=text]` and `[type=password]` but still not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jQuery.Placeholder` plugin is changing the `type` property of your password `input` to `text` instead of password in order to correctly show the placeholder text (only when there's no native browser support for HTML5 `placeholder` attribute).

Hence in IE this CSS rule of yours:

```
.form-1 input[type=password] { etc... }
```

doesn't get applied.

Apply a new `.password` class to your input and change your CSS accordingly:

```
.form-1 input[type=password], .form-1 input.password {

 <input class="password" type="password" name='senha' placeholder="Senha" required />
```